# Moqui and GDPR's right to erasure requirements

Tags: moqui

I'm looking into the erasing of personal details to meet the requirements of Europe's GDPR regulations. Specifically, the right to erasure requirements under GDPR's article 17 – also known as the "right to be forgotten".

Obviously in Moqui we generally don't delete ContactMech or related records, rather we expire the PartyContactMech record. In addition, we disable parties rather than delete them. My understanding is that that is not sufficient in certain cases under these regulations.

My current train of thought has been towards deleting the party's Person or Organization entries, and then searching through existing and expired PartyContactMech records for the ContactMechs and associated addresses and phone numbers to completely delete them too.

Is that an acceptable solution, and/or perhaps I might not be understanding correctly why PostalAddress and so on is immutable?

Any insights on this much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Don't forget to keep, on your train of though, legal retention requirements. Like: User asks for deletion today, but you need to keep records for 3 more years. So you have to process twice the request!

Comment: Yes, certainly there are exceptions that apply to individual requests, such as the one you cited. The use case that will be most common though will be the deletion of aged records, where you cannot justify keeping customer data beyond a reasonable time limit. For example, cancelled quotes or enquiries, where you had no further contact with the prospect since the defined number of years that you have set out in your GDPR policy etc.

Comment: In the conversations I've had about GDPR and Moqui it is always more of a conversation about GDPR. It's a somewhat complex law and comes down to one thing for each company: their privacy and related policies. No system can implement GDPR, not specific enough, have to implement to privacy/etc policies that are deemed GDPR compliant. So far not much has been done in Moqui because it is not really used for social networks and such, it is for transactional ERP and ecommerce systems and there are exclusions in GDPR for data that must be kept for legal and certain other reasons.

Comment: Being more specific then, there would be a need for something like 'erasure' in handling leads, along the lines of recent mantle issue 'add customerStatusId to party for leads application' etc. You cannot justify keeping data on leads that go nowhere beyond a reasonable time limit, according to the new regulations.

Comment: Will it potentially compromise the system to delete these records, as I outline in par.3 of the OP? Keeping just the partyId?

Comment: You might consider scrambling the personal data (ID numbers, etc) while not deleting the record itself.